# What happens when a site fails to meet the beta requirements?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, beta-phase

What happens when a site makes it to beta, but isn't good enough to become a real site by your requirements? Will it be removed from SE altogether? Or will it be in beta forever? I'm just wondering..

Comment: It goes to SE heaven

Comment: @Juan Manuel, i would hate to go to SE hell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleted.

from the [faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> 4.Beta. Perhaps the most important phase. This is the actual, live site
>   set up on a "probationary" basis to
>   see if people will use it. It is very
>   important to participate early. The
>   earliest questions will set the tone
>   and topic of the site for a long time.
>   This is also the time to spread the
>   word via Twitter, blogs, and email far
>   and wide. **If the site does not get
>   used, it will be deleted.** Each site is
>   accessible through two URLs:

Comment: I find this to be the digital analog of a lobotomy, but crueler and [probably unnecessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359676/how-can-we-preserve-area51-sites-that-get-closed-during-the-beta).

Answer (score 2):

The questions from Gadgets were redistributed to the Apple, Android and Gaming sites.