# What happens to the questions after a Stack Exchange beta site closes?

Tags: support, questions, beta-sites

When a Stack Exchange site labeled *beta* closes, what happens to the questions that were posted on the site? Do they ever get archived somewhere, or are they all just gone?

Comment: Duplicate of: [If a Beta site closes, are the questions and answers lost?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260687/348196) (hint: read past the accepted answer.)

Comment: See also: [How can we preserve Area 51 sites that get closed during the beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359676/348196)

Answer (score 1):

Yes a "data dump" is typically provided as a `.zip` file, as they did for [Theoretical Physics SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics) (see the banner at the top!) when it closed down. **But we've been told that Public Beta sites won't be closing down anymore unless there's not enough mods to keep it running.**

Answer (score 1):

To complement the existing answer, sometimes no data dump is provided, in which case one has to hope the Wayback machine or some other mirroring website archived the removed SE website. Example: [Why has the closed beta site “Big Data” no dump available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267415/178179)